# Excel CurDir() function returns a wrong directory

Tags: excel, vba

I just came across this weird thing of Excel. I tried to use `CurDir()` to get my current working directory, but every time I got was "Users\username\Documents", yet the workbook was on "Users\username\Desktop" (`ThisWorkbook.path` gave the right answer). And I tried this on another computer on which it worked out.

Current OS is Win 8.1 64, Office 2016 Professional Plus.
Another is Win 10, Office 2013 Students ver.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `CurDir` is not necessarily the same as the path where your workbook is saved.  If that's what you want, use `ThisWorkbook.Path` instead.

Comment: It's not weird at all. I can't test it, but I think it might also be affected by the `Default file location:` in the Excel `Save` Options

Comment: @Slai Thank you! You saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

`CurDir` is not necessarily the directory of the active workbook (or any open workbook for that matter). It is the directory that was most recently navigated to in the Open or Save dialogs, or set through VBA.

If you need the path of the current document, you should use `Workbook.Path` or `Workbook.FullName`