# How to get the path+filename of an excel workbook stored in my local OneDrive folder? (as opposed to its URL!)

Tags: excel, onedrive

I have an excel workbook that is stored **locally** on my PC but inside my *OneDrive* sync-ed folder. Whenever I try (from the immediate window and programmatically as well):

```
? Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

I get something like:

> https://d.docs.live.net/c31ceb5b47a36fa2/VBA/learnVBAmacros.xlsb

whereas the real **local** path of my file is:

> C:\Users\viset\OneDrive\VBA\learnVBAmacros.xlsb

How can I retrieve this latter **LOCAL** path to my workbook, instead of its URL on OneDrive?

Comment: you can check ?environ(17) in immediate window

Comment: A solution to this problem is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to your one drive settings and untick the "Use office applications to sync...."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07PCs.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30493994)

Comment: Thank you, good solution if one doesn't need collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Split off the filename and use environment variables for your local OneDrive folder.

```
dim fn as string

fn = ThisWorkbook.FullName
'split off the workbook name if fullname is a url
fn = split(fn, "/")(ubound(split(fn, "/")))
'split off the workbook name if fullname is a local path
fn = Split(fn, "\")(UBound(Split(fn, "\")))
'add the environment var
fn = environ("onedrive") & "\" & fn

'check to see if it exists
if len(dir(fn)) > 0 then
    debug.print fn
end if
```

Note that there are OneDrive and OneDriveConsumer environment variables. My own are identical but there must be a reason for each.

Comment: please recheck your code it give following output `C:\Users\kakka\OneDrive\C:\Users\kakka\Documents\environ.xlsm
` to me

Comment: That would depend on whether ThisWorkbook.FullName as a OneDrive URL or a local path. The op has stated that ThisWorkbook.FullName was returning the OneDrive URL and I provided a conversion for that situation. Of course, a simple check could easily be generated.

Answer (score 0):

This works, sorry but I can not remember where I found it

```
Sub GetDocLocalPath_Test()

  MsgBox GetDocLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName)

End Sub

Function GetDocLocalPath(docPath As String) As String
'Gel Local Path NOT URL to Onedrive
Const strcOneDrivePart As String = "https://d.docs.live.net/"
Dim strRetVal As String, bytSlashPos As Byte

  strRetVal = docPath & "\"
  If Left(LCase(docPath), Len(strcOneDrivePart)) = strcOneDrivePart Then 'yep, it's the OneDrive path
    'locate and remove the "remote part"
    bytSlashPos = InStr(Len(strcOneDrivePart) + 1, strRetVal, "/")
    strRetVal = Mid(docPath, bytSlashPos)
    'read the "local part" from the registry and concatenate
    strRetVal = RegKeyRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\OneDrive") & strRetVal
    strRetVal = Replace(strRetVal, "/", "\") 'slashes in the right direction
    strRetVal = Replace(strRetVal, "%20", " ") 'a space is a space once more
End If
GetDocLocalPath = strRetVal

End Function

Function RegKeyRead(i_RegKey As String) As String
Dim myWS As Object

  On Error Resume Next
  'access Windows scripting
  Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  'read key from registry
  RegKeyRead = myWS.RegRead(i_RegKey)
End Function
```

Comment: You probably got this solution from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive#:~:text=Function%20RegKeyRead(i_RegKey,%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20GetDocLocalPath%20%3D%20strRetVal "how to get physical path instead of URL (OneDrive) - (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/...)"). The solution was originally written by [Cooz2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/cooz2) and adapted for VBA by [LucasHol](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/lucashol).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution in very easy.

If your file is pending for synchronization on OneDrive you will have the value of `ThisWorkBook.Path` as an URL address.

Unless your file synchronizes the value of `ThisWorkBook.Path` will contain the local address of the file.

[image: here you have the results]

Answer (score 0):

Combining a few earlier answers, I went with this function.  It makes fewer assumptions about the format of a OneDrive URL and it uses the environment instead of the registry.

Note: it does *still* make assumptions about the OneDrive URL. Specifically:

- Assumed to start with "https:"
- Assumed only one URL path-component after the hostname
- Assumed that what follows will match the local file-system

```
Function GetWorkbookDirectory() As String

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sOneDrive As String
    Dim iPos As Integer
    
    sPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    ' Is this a OneDrive path?
    If Left(sPath, 6) = "https:" Then
        ' Find the start of the "local part" of the name
        iPos = InStr(sPath, "//")           ' Find start of URL hostname
        iPos = InStr(iPos + 2, sPath, "/")  ' Find end of URL hostname
        iPos = InStr(iPos + 1, sPath, "/")  ' Find start of local part
        
        ' Join that with the local location for OneDrive files
        sPath = Environ("OneDrive") & Mid(sPath, iPos)
        sPath = Replace(sPath, "/", Application.PathSeparator)
    End If
    
    GetWorkbookDirectory = sPath

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using FileSystemObject.

```
Dim fso as FileSystemObject, localPath as String, localFullFileName as String
localPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name))
localFullFileName = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using CurDir

```
Function GetFilePath() As String
    GetFilePath = CurDir
End Function
```

Comment: `CurDir` does not necessarily return the path of the current workbook. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274201/12287457) for more information. For a solution for the problem this question is about, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).